# Zend form checkbox label before input

Tags: jquery, zend-framework, zend-form

Spent hours crawling through Google, I need to implement jQuery Button on a list of checkboxes, the problem I have is when I output the form element the code is inserting the INPUT inside the  and I need it outside the label. Here's how it is outputting:

```
<label for="checkbox-1"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="checkbox-1" value="1" checked="checked">3DCrafter</label>
```

Here is my form element with decorators:

```
$checkbox->addMultiOption($prev,$p);
        $checkbox->setAttrib('id', 'checkbox');
        $checkbox->setSeparator('  ');
        $checkbox->setDecorators(array(
           array('ViewHelper'),
           array('Errors', array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'error')),
           array('Label', array('tag' => 'span')),
           array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'label')),
        ));
```

Heres how I am outputting the form element:

```
<?php echo $this->formSoftware->checkbox;?>
```

Anybody got any ideas how to do this?  Or use jQuery Button on checkbox in Zend?

Comment: Could you please add the expected html output that u desire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One (not very satisfying) solution is to use jQuery to setup the DOM as expected :

```
//HTML
//the checkboxes are children of their associated label
<div id="container">
    <label for="cb1"><input type="checkbox" id="cb1" name="cb1" />Checkbox 1</label>
    <label for="cb2"><input type="checkbox" id="cb2" name="cb2" checked="checked" />Checkbox 2</label>
    <label for="cb3"><input type="checkbox" id="cb3" name="cb3" />Checkbox 3</label>
</div>

//javascript
//for each label : find its target input among its descendants,
//and place it before the label
$('#container').find('label').each(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('for');
    $(this).find('#' + id).insertBefore(this);
});

$('#container').buttonset();
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TVFAF/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ZF1 I suggest you create a custom Decorator class which `extends Zend_Form_Decorator_Abstract` and register the path to your custom Decorators by adding `addElementPrefixPath` to your form.

Your custom decorator will need a `render()` method to output the markup you want.

Not sure how that works on ZF2.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the Label decorator prepends to the provided content; This can be controlled by specifying one of the following 'placement' options:

`PREPEND`: render the label before the content.

`APPEND`: render the label after the content.

`IMPLICIT_PREPEND`: render the element inside the label tag, placing the label text before the content.

`IMPLICIT_APPEND`: render the element inside the label tag, placing the label text after the content.

So in your case I think you want PREPEND:

```
$checkbox->addMultiOption($prev,$p);
        $checkbox->setAttrib('id', 'checkbox');
        $checkbox->setSeparator('  ');
        $checkbox->setDecorators(array(
           array('ViewHelper'),
           array('Errors', array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'error')),
           array('Label', array('tag' => 'span', 'placement' => 'PREPEND')),
           array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'label')),
        ));
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I add the code and it still puts the input between the label sadly.

Answer (score 0):

Here getLabel() Method will help you to print Label.

```
<?php echo $this->formSoftware->checkbox->getLabel();?>
<?php echo $this->formSoftware->checkbox;?>
```